# Is any axiom consistent with ZFC also consistent with NBG?

Tags: logic, set-theory

In particular, is it possible to add Tarski's axiom (of universes) to a finitely axiomatized version of NBG (to create a finitely axiomatized version of TG set theory) and still be as consistent as ZFC+TA?

Comment: When you write NBG, do you mean a one-sorted version or a two-sorted version?

Comment: One sorted, with Tarski's axiom restricted to classes that are sets.

Comment: That's what I wanted to verify. In that case, the axiom "$\lnot (\exists x)(\forall y)[y \in x]$" is consistent with ZFC (provable, actually) and disprovable in NBG.  Of course this is because we have to interpret axioms of ZFC in a different way when we read them in NBG - in particular, we have to rewrite the quantifiers of ZFC to only quantify over sets. If we add the interpreted version of Tarski's ZFC axiom to NBG, the result will be consistent.  However, Tarski's axiom *as it stands* would also be inconsistent with NBG, because $V$ itself cannot be a member of anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  NBG is conservative over ZFC, meaning that any theorem of NBG involving only set variables is also a theorem of ZFC.  So for any axiom $\varphi$ (in the language of ZFC), NBG proves $\neg\varphi$ iff ZFC proves $\neg\varphi$.  That is, $\varphi$ is consistent with NBG iff $\varphi$ is consistent with ZFC.

[As clarified in the comments, this answer is treating NBG as a two-sorted theory, so variables referring to classes are new symbols in the language.  If you treat it as a one-sorted theory, then in order to convert a statement of ZFC into a statement of NBG, you need to modify it to assert that each variable appearing in it is a set.  The correct statement is then that a statement in the language of ZFC is a theorem of ZFC iff the modified version of it is a theorem of NBG.  So if you want to take an axiom which is consistent with ZFC and get an axiom consistent with NBG, you first have to modify it in this way.]

Comment: Also, do you know why articles say "ZFC cannot be finitely axiomatized"? Doesn't the existence of a finite conservative extension contradict that?

Comment: It is true that ZFC cannot be finitely axiomatized (assuming it is consistent).  That statement has a very precise meaning: there is no finite set of sentences in the language of ZFC that generates the same theory as ZFC.  The fact that there is a finite set of sentences in a larger language whose consequences in the language of ZFC are the same in no way contradicts that.

Comment: @Akari Akaori: in light of the clarification you gave, perhaps the confusion is that NBG is not literally conservative over ZFC when they are both viewed as one-sorted theories. Instead, what we get is an interpretation, a map that takes a sentence $\phi$ of ZFC and gives a sentence $\hat \phi$ of NBG so that ZFC proves $\phi$ if and only if NBG proves $\hat \phi$ - that is not literally a "conservative extension". In this answer, a different kind of interpretation is used, so that NBG has two sorts, in which case we can $\hat \phi$ just be $\phi$.